# Selenium IDE not finding xpath elements which contain variables during Run, but valid when editing/debugging

Tags: xpath, selenium-ide

I'm using Selenium IDE 1.7.2 and Firefox 10.0.2

In the page which I'm writing a test script for, there is a table cell with the following literal xpath value:

```
.//*[@id='tab-22-div']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[7]/div
```

I have a variable named PDTabDiv which contains the value: 22

The Selenium IDE script step:

```
storeText | .//*[@id='tab-22-div']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[7]/div | MyVar
```

works correctly both when executing the step in edit mode and when the step is executed after pressing Run.  When I state that it works correctly, the cell's value is stored in the MyVar variable and the step executes without error.

However, attempting several techniques to use a variable to drive the number within the 'tab-22-div' portion of the xpath do not result in the same success.

I can successfully produce a valid-looking xpath string using this approach:

```
storeExpression | .//*[@id='tab-${PDTabDiv}-div']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[7]/div | MyXpath
```

The MyXpath variable does contain: .//*[@id='tab-22-div']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[7]/div
However the following step, while successful in edit mode, reports the following error when the step executes after pressing Run:

```
STEP
storeText | xpath=${MyXpath} | MyVar

ERROR
[error] Element xpath=.//*[@id='tab-22-div']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[7]/div not found
```

The Selenese type command did not seem to exhibit the issue though, I was able to run this step via Run and it always placed the value 100 in the correct field (which is in a cell):

```
type | xpath=.//*[@id='document.budget.budgetPeriod[0].budgetLineItem[${MyLoopIndex}].budgetPersonnelDetailsList[0].percentEffort'] | 100
```

Perhaps I'm not using the correct approach.  Any assistance would be gratefully appreciated.  A little background, I'm using the DataDriven plugin to process several records against a web site, and the locators rows differ each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be while running, required element does not load when your command executes. That's why your are getting such error.
Keep `pause` command before execution of `storeText` command

Comment: Although the page is loaded and data elements visually appear to be present prior to the step in question, inserting a pause after the page load did cause an instance of success!  I removed the pause and changed the Click step which loaded to page to a ClickAndWait and am seeing if that approach ends up solving this without using a hardcoded pause.

Comment: It appears that the ClickAndWait approach is resolving the issue, thank you for the lead!

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the command `waitForElementPresent` before calling `storeText` ?

Comment: Thanks! However, there are 5 steps before storeText which are executing correctly, and at before those 5 steps, the page is already loaded.
The waitForElementPresent specifying xpath=${MyXpath} succeeds, and the storeText succeeds but does not actually store the value from that xpath locator.
This test also ran successfully when specifying literal values and only fails when using variables, even though the variables contain the expected proper values at the time the step executes.
I could work around this entire issue by using gotoIf statements, but that is inelegant and not very efficient.